# I checked 'Add unambiguous imports on the fly' option, but it's not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I checked 'Add unambiguous imports on the fly' option in Android Studio 1.4.
[checked 'Add unambiguous imports on the fly' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnd3I.png)
But,it didn't auto import the pakage.
[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZqby.png)
Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you explicity name the package, i.e.

```
android.widget.Button
```

then there is no need to import that package.

If you use

```
Button btn;
```

instead, it should import.

Comment: I didn't mean that. If I input 'Button btn', the result is 'android.widget.Button btn'.

Comment: That's a different problem them. What does Android Studio show if you hover over 'btb'?